# File search APIs on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, file, qt

In my project, I need to show all files on user's drive filtered by the filename with a text line. Are there any APIs to do such thing?

On Windows, I know, there're FindFirstFile and FindNextFile functions in WinAPI.

I use C++/Qt.

Comment: [find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find)?

Comment: @tjameson this is command-line utility, I'm interested in a C++ function

Comment: I meant you could shell out. Can you use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)?

Comment: @tjameson I can shell out, but this way isn't really good. And I prefer to don't use boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt provides the [QDirIterator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdiriterator.html) class:

```
QDirIterator iter("/", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    QString current = iter.next();
    // Do something with 'current'...
}
```

Comment: Is it enough fast? For example, it takes about 3 seconds to find about 32000 files using the WinAPI functions mentioned in the question by the pattern '*'. I'm not really sure Qt works so fast.

Comment: @gxoptg These functions are as fast, or slow, as the underlying operating system or file system. There's little to none speedup you can get by using different functions for doing this.

Comment: +1 This is probably the best option since it's cross platform. For linux specific, I like @nos's answer because it decouples the application from qt.

Comment: @gxoptg Keep in mind that QDiriterator is implemented using FindFirstFile()/etc. under the hood on windows.

Answer (score 4):

There's [ftw](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/ftw.h.html)() and linux has [fts](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html)()

Besides those, you can iterate directories, using e.g. opendir8/[readdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html)()

Comment: None of those support globbing though.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a Unix command, you could do this :

`find source_dir -name 'regex'`

If you want to do it C++ style, I'd suggest to use [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm). It's a very powerfull cross platform library.
Of course, you will have to add an additional library.

Here is an example :

```
  std::vector<std::string> list_files(const std::string& root, const bool& recursive, const std::string& filter, const bool& regularFilesOnly)
        {
            namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
            fs::path rootPath(root);

            // Throw exception if path doesn't exist or isn't a directory.
            if (!fs::exists(rootPath)) {
                throw std::exception("rootPath does not exist");
            }
            if (!fs::is_directory(rootPath)) {
                throw std::exception("rootPath is not a directory.");
            }

            // List all the files in the directory
            const std::regex regexFilter(filter);
            auto fileList = std::vector<std::string>();

            fs::directory_iterator end_itr;
            for( fs::directory_iterator it(rootPath); it != end_itr; ++it) {

                std::string filepath(it->path().string());

                // For a directory
                if (fs::is_directory(it->status())) {

                    if (recursive && it->path().string() != "..") {
                        // List the files in the directory
                        auto currentDirFiles = list_files(filepath, recursive, filter, regularFilesOnly);
                        // Add to the end of the current vector
                        fileList.insert(fileList.end(), currentDirFiles.begin(), currentDirFiles.end());
                    }

                } else if (fs::is_regular_file(it->status())) { // For a regular file
                    if (filter != "" && !regex_match(filepath, regexFilter)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                } else {
                    // something else
                }

                if (regularFilesOnly && !fs::is_regular_file(it->status())) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Add the file or directory to the list
                fileList.push_back(filepath);
            }

            return fileList;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `glob`
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html
has the advantage of existing on a lot of Unices (Solaris for sure) as it is part of POSIX.

Ok, it's not C++ but pure C.

Answer (score 0):

Look `man find`. `find` supports filtering by a mask ( `-name` option for examole)